# Google maps, cannot place marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have been unable to play down even a basic marker at the LatLng position and I am unsure on how to fix it. Whenever I try to place a marker, the whole div tag and map goes away.

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>

<script>
function myMap() {
var mapProp= {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(-36.934601, 174.915836),
    zoom:15,
};
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
}
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDRqDMSVnEAKKE7vPz3cWiJ9Ge6lLLBtQ4&callback=myMap"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the value of myLatLng?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define myLatLng

```
var myLatLng = {lat:-36.934601, lng: 174.915836};
```

The complete code becomes:

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>

<script>
function myMap() {
var mapProp= {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(-36.934601, 174.915836),
    zoom:15,
};
var myLatLng = {lat:-36.934601, lng: 174.915836};
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
}
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDRqDMSVnEAKKE7vPz3cWiJ9Ge6lLLBtQ4&callback=myMap"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that earlier but I must have done something wrong, thanks for your help